# Adding Counter in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have below code in my shell script which will keep on sleeping if it doesn't finds any file. And it sleeps for half an hour but currently I don't have any counter like only execute the below code 20 times and then exit the program if the files are still are not there (means don't do anything after 20 checks and exit the full script).

What's the best way to do this problem? So that I am also aware by looking at the emails that it has tried 20 times.

Hope I am clear enough.

```
while true; do
  if /home/hadoop/latest/bin/hadoop fs -ls /apps/hdtech/bds/quality-rt/dt=$DATE_YEST_FORMAT2 then
       echo "Files Present" | mailx -s "File Present"  -r admin@host.com admin@host.com
       break
  else
       echo "Sleeping for half an hour" | mailx -s "Time to Sleep Now"  -r admin@host.com admin@host.com
       sleep 1800
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Here's how you might implement a counter:

```
counter=0
while true; do
  if /home/hadoop/latest/bin/hadoop fs -ls /apps/hdtech/bds/quality-rt/dt=$DATE_YEST_FORMAT2 then
       echo "Files Present" | mailx -s "File Present"  -r admin@host.com admin@host.com
       exit 0
  elif [[ "$counter" -gt 20 ]]; then
       echo "Counter: $counter times reached; Exiting loop!"
       exit 1
  else
       counter=$((counter+1))
       echo "Counter: $counter time(s); Sleeping for another half an hour" | mailx -s "Time to Sleep Now"  -r admin@host.com admin@host.com
       sleep 1800
  fi
done
```

**Some Explanations:**

- `counter=$((counter+1))` - this is how you can increment a counter. The `$` for `counter` is optional inside the double parentheses in this case.
- `elif [[ "$counter" -gt 20 ]]; then` - this checks whether `$counter` is not greater than `20`. If so, it outputs the appropriate message and breaks out of your while loop.

Comment: Thanks sampson for the suggestion. Instead of doing `break` in `elif` is there any way I can exit the script? Why I am asking this is because after `done` line I have lot more code to be executed so it was executed only when the files were present but after adding this check of counter, I don't want to execute those code as well after checking for 20 times if the files are still are not there.

Comment: @TechGeeky To exit the script itself, do `exit 0` (if terminating as expected) or `exit 1` (if terminating and you want to indicate some error has happened)

Comment: I tried the above code and I am getting exception at `counter=$((counter+1))` this line as `$` unexpected. Why is it so? I am running the above script as `sh -x test1.sh`

Comment: @TechGeeky: Hmm, it's working for me in bash. Try `counter=$(($counter+1))`?

Comment: @sampson-chen Hi, this solition helped me too, but I missed the space directly after the `[[` and got an error with `bad pattern`.
Can you explain the reason for that?

Comment: Don't why but, `counter=$((counter+1))` worked for me while `let counter++` didn't.

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
counter=0
while true; do
  if /home/hadoop/latest/bin/hadoop fs -ls /apps/hdtech/bds/quality-rt/dt=$DATE_YEST_FORMAT2 then
       echo "Files Present" | mailx -s "File Present"  -r admin@host.com admin@host.com
       break
  elif [[ "$counter" -gt 20 ]]; then
       echo "Counter limit reached, exit script."
       exit 1
  else
       let counter++
       echo "Sleeping for another half an hour" | mailx -s "Time to Sleep Now"  -r admin@host.com admin@host.com
       sleep 1800
  fi
done
```

**Explanation**

- `break` - if files are present, it will break and allow the script to process the files.
- `[[ "$counter" -gt 20 ]]` - if the counter variable is greater than 20, the script will exit.
- `let counter++` - increments the counter by 1 at each pass.

Comment: I like the `let counter++` syntax than the old one with a bunch of dollars :)

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
counter=0
while [[ "$counter" -lt 20 ]] 
do
  if [[ $counter -gt 0 ]] ; then
    echo "Counter: $counter time(s); Sleeping for another half an hour" | mailx -s "Time to Sleep Now"  -r admin@host.com admin@host.com
    sleep 1800  
  fi
  if /home/hadoop/latest/bin/hadoop fs -ls /apps/hdtech/bds/quality-rt/dt=$DATE_YEST_FORMAT2 ; then
       echo "Files Present" | mailx -s "File Present"  -r admin@host.com admin@host.com
       exit 0
  fi
  : $((counter++))
done

echo "Counter: $counter times reached; Exiting loop!"
exit 1
```

Here's another take on this. I've added this bit of code to illustrate these points:

1. The `while` can take your counter as the condition - this removes the need to check the variable value in the loop.
2. Since the if branches cause the loop to end anyway ( via break or exit ) there is no need for the final `else`.
3. I've provided a different syntax for increasing the counter.  To be honest, I've never seen koola's version (`let counter++`) but I like it a lot (it's simpler to me).
4. I'm not 100% sure that some of the while loops provide as answers actually loop 20 times.  Rather, I think some of them loop 21 times.
5. The solutions presented actually email the admin an extra time - there is no need to tell the admin that you are sleeping for a half an hour if you are going to be exiting anyway.  I've added an additional if at the beginning of the while loop to avoid the extra email (and sleep).

Here's the output for a run that fails to find files 20 times:

```
Counter: 1 time(s); Sleeping for another half an hour
Counter: 2 time(s); Sleeping for another half an hour
...
Counter: 19 time(s); Sleeping for another half an hour
Counter: 20 times reached; Exiting loop!
```

The short of if is that we check for files 20 times, but only sleep 19 times.

Answer (score 2):

You may do this with a `for` loop instead of a `while`:

```
max_loop=20
for ((count = 0; count < max_loop; count++)); do
  if /home/hadoop/latest/bin/hadoop fs -ls /apps/hdtech/bds/quality-rt/dt=$DATE_YEST_FORMAT2 then
       echo "Files Present" | mailx -s "File Present"  -r admin@host.com admin@host.com
       break
  else
       echo "Sleeping for half an hour" | mailx -s "Time to Sleep Now"  -r admin@host.com admin@host.com
       sleep 1800
  fi
done

if [ "$count" -eq "$max_loop" ]; then
  echo "Maximum number of trials reached" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: This is the best answer.  `for` loops were made for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There is a shell tool that produces a list of numbers, but I couldn't remember what it was called.  I found question above and its answers when I was searching for that shell tool.  Later, I remembered that the shell tool I was looking for is `seq`.  (It may not be available on every system, but mine, with macOS 13.6, has it.)

Here's an implementation of the script using `seq`…

```
maxAttempts=20
for i in `seq ${maxAttempts}`; do
  if /home/hadoop/latest/bin/hadoop fs -ls /apps/hdtech/bds/quality-rt/dt=$DATE_YEST_FORMAT2; then
       echo "Files Present" | mailx -s "File Present"  -r admin@host.com admin@host.com
       exit 0
  else
       echo "Sleeping for half an hour" | mailx -s "Time to Sleep Now"  -r admin@host.com admin@host.com
       sleep 1800
  fi
done

echo "Failed after ${maxAttempts} attempts."
exit 1
```