# Creating a .txt file in bash script given an input argument

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a program that will create a new text file for each iteration of a number ie passing in a parameter 3 and setting num=3 should create text.txt and the end result should have text3.txt, text2.txt, and text1.txt. I know that I need to use the touch command to create a new file, but I am unable to figure out how to change that specific variable when I create it.

Comment: Similar questions have been answered countless times here on SO. For example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638670/adding-counter-in-shell-script

Comment: Note that you don't want the accepted answer on the dupe (which is only good with constant values) but the runner-up.

Comment: Thank you so much!